# How to include CTime in my vc++ code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a need to use CTime in my code. I tried to add the header file "atltime.h" to this code. But now, I am getting so many errors in compiling. Every error is coming from the header file "afxconv.h". I searched msdn for CTime, but they didn't describe about this( may be I yet to see the proper page). I am using VisualStudio-2008, 64 bit. Can anybody point me the correct direction?

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Impossible to guess at without see the first few error messages.  Document your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included one file from code project, in that it uses some ASSERT,AfxisValidString. They included afx.h, for that. It is also the header for CTime. So, when I removed, and added atltime.h, then the ASSERT related things threw the errors. Sorry, I wated some of your precious time. I am going to vote to delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are having a conflict with the MFC and ATL version of CTime. Since you specify MFC in your tag I suspect that you want the MFC verion. The atltime.h is for ATL projects. Afx.h has CTime for MFC which AFAIK is normally always included in the stdafx.h

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us your errors?

this code works just fine on a 32 bit computer with a win32 project with atl.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atltime.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CTime ct;
    printf("day of week %d\n",ct.GetDayOfWeek());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have  `#include <time.h>`. Check the requirements part of the link. [MSDN CTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59w5xcdy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Your link refers to `ctime()` function, not to MFC's `CTime` class!